# Sum over subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ of terms involving a product over that subset

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations, products

I'm attempting to perform a sum, using products, using all possible combinations, in a function.

How would I go about doing this? (I really need to find something that works.)

For example, say I wanted to, for a range of values, say $n = 1$ to $3$, find the sum of

$\dfrac{g(x)}{f(1)f(2)}$ , $\dfrac{g(x)}{f(1)f(3)}$ , $\dfrac{g(x)}{f(2)f(3)}$ , $\dfrac{g(x)}{f(1)f(2)f(3)}$

If I were to use $1$ to $4$, I would be summing:

$\dfrac{g(x)}{f(1)f(2)}$ , $\dfrac{g(x)}{f(1)f(3)}$ , $\dfrac{g(x)}{f(1)f(4)}$ , $\dfrac{g(x)}{f(2)f(3)}$ , $\dfrac{g(x)}{f(2)f(4)}$ , $\dfrac{g(x)}{f(3)f(4)}$ ,

$\dfrac{g(x)}{f(1)f(2)f(3)}$ , $\dfrac{g(x)}{f(1)f(2)f(4)}$ , $\dfrac{g(x)}{f(1)f(3)f(4)}$ , $\dfrac{g(x)}{f(2)f(3)f(4)}$ ,

$\dfrac{g(x)}{f(1)f(2)f(3)f(4)}$

You get the idea. The sum I would need to do for a range of values obviously balloons really fast. Going to $20$ or $100$ would be ludicrous.

Is there any notation for this at all?

I can't see how to do it with any of sigma, pi, or combinatorial notation.

I'm finishing a degree in Computer Science, so I can easily calculate such a thing. I just need it on paper for the sake of some proofs I want to attempt.

What can I do? 
Thanks!

Comment: @induktio I'm afraid that's not true. For instance this is easily calculated with nested for cycles.

Comment: Are you looking for some sort of closed form expression for the sum? Or just the appropriate notation to deal with talking about the sum?

Comment: Is $g(x)$ a common factor to every term in the summation?  If so, we can distribute it out from the summation.  Along the same lines, is the function $f(n)$ known?  Does it have any special properties?

Comment: Do you know how to compute following polynomial?
$$\prod_{k=1}^n \left(x - \frac{1}{f(k)}\right)
= x^n - c_1 x^{n-1} + c_2 x^{n-2} \cdots + (-1)^n c_n$$
Sums of the form
$$\prod_{1\le j_1 < j_2 < \cdots < j_m \le n}\frac{1}{f(j_1)f(j_2)\cdots f(j_m)}$$
is simply equal to the coefficient $c_m$.

Comment: Do you just want notation? You are just summing over the powerset of $[n]$. $\displaystyle \sum_{\begin{array}( p \in 2^{[n]} \\ |p|>1 \end{array}} \frac{g(x)}{\prod p_i}$.

Comment: By code, yes, I could compute that if I knew what they all were and had a function f() or pointer to it. It's something like (squished in comments): int ans=1; for(k=1..n) { ans *= x-(1/f(k)); } return ans;

Comment: @Drew If you think that is the answer, post it as one. Yes, the power set. I'll review it and mark it as correct later if it is, since I have to close my laptop and go to work.

Comment: @AndrewRoss just the proper notation for a proof. I can't find appropriate notation for it anywhere. Maybe I need to learn the proper way to handle a power set. I just need to express any size without it ever getting bigger (arbitrarily large n).

Comment: I think @achillehui's answer is better. $$ g(x) \prod \left (1 + \tfrac{1}{f(k)} \right) \;\; - \;\; g(x)\left( 1 + \sum \tfrac{1}{f(k)} \right)$$

Comment: I see. I think @achillehui's answer is nice too, although I think the second expression in achillehiu's comment should be a sum not a product?

Comment: @AndrewRoss oops, you are right, it should be a sum instead of product.

Comment: @Drew you should post an answer as well, it might be useful for somebody in the future

Comment: Alright I'll make a post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make the answer nicer, let's suppose you are also summing
  $$ \frac{g(x)}{1}, \; \frac{g(x)}{f(1)}, \; \frac{g(x)}{f(2)}, \; ... \, , \; \frac{g(x)}{f(n)}$$

If you don't want these terms you can just subtract the following from the answer

$$\begin{array} (  g(x) + \sum \tfrac{g(x)}{f(k)} \end{array}$$

---

One way to write this is as a sum over the subsets of $[n] = \{1,2,...,n\}$. For example $\tfrac{g(x)}{f(2)f(3)f(4)}$ would correspond to the subset $\{2,3,4\}$. The set of subsets is known as the power set, which is often denoted $2^{[n]}$.

$$ \sum_{p \, \in \, 2^{[n]}} \frac{g(x)}{\prod f(p_i)}$$

This formula does make it clear what you are counting, but it's not particularly useful since there are $2^n$ summands. A better answer is the following

$$ \\ g(x) \prod_{k=1}^n \left(1 + \frac{1}{f(k)} \right) \\ $$

To see how this corresponds to your sum, let's forget about $g(x)$ and take a look at the product

$$ \\ \left(1 + \tfrac{1}{f(1)} \right) \left( 1 + \tfrac{1}{f(2)} \right) 
\left(1 + \tfrac{1}{f(3)} \right) \; ... \; \left(1 + \tfrac{1}{f(n)} \right) \\$$

When you multiply this out you will get a sum of $2^n$ terms, just like when summing over the subsets. Each term corresponds to selecting either the (1) or $\tfrac{1}{f(i)}$ in each bracket and then multiplying them together. Suppose I wanted the $\tfrac{1}{f(2)f(3)f(4)}$ term. I choose $\tfrac{1}{f(2)},\, \tfrac{1}{f(3)}, \, \tfrac{1}{f(4)}$ from their respective brackets and choose (1) from all the rest.